# How can I convert application.yml to command line flags?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here's a snippet from my `application.yml`:

```
graphql.playground:
  enabled: true
```

How can I convert it to a command line to sth like:

```
java -jar app.jar --graphql.playground.enabled=false
```

Comment: what is the problem? is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

It should be work fine with your `application.yml` and  command line also as well, my suggestion is try to debug then find the root cause.